# daily cron run terminated as it exceeded max run time

Tags: python, django, cron, openshift

I have no idea why my cron is running 20 minutes and it is terminated. On openshift, if you run cron, it gets killed after 5 minutes. If you run with nohup, it gets killed after 20 minutes.
This is my error log on cron_daily. File `update_dave_list` was running 20 minutes:

```
Thu Nov 19 03:08:08 EST 2015: START daily cron run
__________________________________________________________________________
/var/lib/openshift/55a000094/app-root/runtime/repo//.openshift/cron/daily/update_dave_list:
WARNING:py.warnings:/var/lib/openshift/55a0000094/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_crontab-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/django_crontab/crontab.py:13: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.uti$
  from django.utils.importlib import import_module
/usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/cron/bin/cron_runjobs.sh: line 114: 181616 Killed                  $executor "$SCRIPTS_DIR"
Warning: daily cron run terminated as it exceeded max run time
__________________________________________________________________________
Thu Nov 19 03:28:09 EST 2015: END daily cron run - status=137
__________________________________________________________________________
```

The problem is that `update_dave_list` takes only ~20 seconds to run:
`update_dave_list` content:

```
#!/bin/bash
date
nohup /var/lib/openshift/55000094/python/virtenv/bin/python /var/lib/openshift/55000094/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/digrin/manage.py crontab run 18e10bf4fb745d8a480230a3 # update dave lists
date
```

output:

```
Št nov 19 03:43:47 EST 2015
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
Št nov 19 03:44:05 EST 2015
```

Problem is also that none of my other daily crons are run if one is killed. 
Oh and here is the code in case you wonder what am I running for 20 seconds:

```
def update_dave_list():
    # if settings.ON_OPENSHIFT:
    response = urlopen("http://www.dripinvesting.org/tools/U.S.DividendChampions.xls")
    excell = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=response.read())
    for sheet in range(0,3): #for champions, challengers and contenders
        worksheet = excell.sheet_by_index(sheet)
        list, created = List.objects.get_or_create(name=worksheet.name, short_name=worksheet.name,
                                                   source="http://www.dripinvesting.org/tools/tools.asp")
        num_rows = worksheet.nrows - 1
        curr_row = 5
        symbol_list = []
        while curr_row < num_rows:
            curr_row += 1
            symbol = worksheet.cell(curr_row, 1)
            if symbol.ctype != 1: #break if you are out of symbol
                break
                #print  cell.value.replace(".", "-")
            symbol_list.append(unify_symbol(symbol.value))
            industry = worksheet.cell(curr_row, 2)
            sector = worksheet.cell(curr_row, 77)
            years = worksheet.cell(curr_row, 3)
            try:
                list_stock, created = ListStock.objects.get_or_create(stock=Stock.objects.get(symbol=unify_symbol(symbol.value)))
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                AddStock.objects.get_or_create(symbol=unify_symbol(symbol.value))
                continue
            list_stock.industry = industry.value
            list_stock.years_paying = years.value
            if sector.ctype == 1:
                if list_stock.stock.sector == None:
                    sector_obj, created = Sector.objects.get_or_create(name=sector.value)
                    list_stock.stock.sector = sector_obj
                    list_stock.stock.save()
            list_stock.save()
            #add stocks to list
            list.stocks.add(list_stock)
        #delete removed stocks
        for list_stock in list.stocks.all():
            if list_stock.stock.symbol not in symbol_list:
                list.stocks.remove(list_stock)
    return
```

But it is probably not dependent on code, since if I run my cron file (`./update_dave_list`) it finishes in 20 seconds, when run by cron it will not finish. Any idea what problem here might be?

---

**EDIT1:**
So I tried to comment out file `update_dave_list` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#/var/lib/openshift/55a0310e4382ec4b84000094/python/virtenv/bin/python /var/lib/openshift/55a0310e4382ec4b84000094/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/digrin/manage.py crontab run 18e10bf4fb92741b69745d8a480230a3 # update dave lists
```

My daily cron folder on openshift looks like this:

```
drwx------. 2 55a00094 55a00094 4096 nov 22 17:55 .
drwx------. 7 55a00094 55a00094 4096 nov 22 17:39 ..
-rw-------. 1 55a00094 55a00094    0 nov 22 17:37 .gitignore
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 55a00094 55a00094  236 nov 22 17:37 update_dave_list
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 55a00094 55a00094  235 nov 22 17:37 update_dgr
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 55a00094 55a00094  244 nov 22 17:37 update_ex_dividends
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 55a00094 55a00094  250 nov 22 17:37 update_frequency
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 55a00094 55a00094  236 nov 22 17:37 update_industry
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 55a00094 55a00094  472 nov 22 17:37 update_stocks
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 55a00094 55a00094  243 nov 22 17:37 update_years_paying
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 55a00094 55a00094  252 nov 22 17:37 watcher
```

After I commented out dave list update, this is log from **cron_daily.log**:

```
__________________________________________________________________________
Mon Nov 23 03:25:54 EST 2015: START daily cron run
__________________________________________________________________________
/usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/cron/bin/cron_runjobs.sh: line 114: 28445 Killed                  $executor "$SCRIPTS_DIR"
Warning: daily cron run terminated as it exceeded max run time
__________________________________________________________________________
Mon Nov 23 03:45:54 EST 2015: END daily cron run - status=137
__________________________________________________________________________
```

I think it means that none of my files are run and error is in cron_runjobs.sh. But I do not get support on openshift and reporting bug does not help (I reported one few weeks ago and no update yet). It is weird that my daily crons do not work, hourly cron work ok.

---

EDIT2:
I tried to restart cron cartridge:

```
rhc cartridge remove cron -a <app>
rhc cartridge add cron -a <app>
```

Did not help:

```
__________________________________________________________________________
Tue Nov 24 03:12:47 EST 2015: START daily cron run
__________________________________________________________________________
/usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/cron/bin/cron_runjobs.sh: line 114: 211644 Killed                  $executor "$SCRIPTS_DIR"
Warning: daily cron run terminated as it exceeded max run time
__________________________________________________________________________
Tue Nov 24 03:32:47 EST 2015: END daily cron run - status=137
__________________________________________________________________________
```

I ma not sure what to do now. If file in daily cron is started, it looks like this:

```
__________________________________________________________________________
Mon Nov 23 13:01:05 EST 2015: START hourly cron run
__________________________________________________________________________
/var/lib/openshift/55a000094/app-root/runtime/repo//.openshift/cron/hourly/add_stocks:
...
```

But daily cron does not run any file in daily directory.

Comment: You could try adding some logging to your function to get some insight as to where it gets hung up when running in the context of the cron, or there might be a way to manually run in that environment. My guess is there's something different between the environments that's causing your script to hang.

Comment: Hi @Nathaniel, thanks for comment. I will check if I can find out under what enviroment is cron running and if I can use it. Check my EDIT1 please.

Comment: What is `cron_runjobs.sh` line 114?

Comment: It is a openshift file that runs cron I guess. I should not alter that. But I have a quess what might be the problem. I'll post answer tomorrow if I am right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I think I found out what the problem was.
First of all, I can force to run daily cron like this:

```
/usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/cron/bin/cron_runjobs.sh daily
```

This was my log from daily cron:

```
__________________________________________________________________________
Wed Nov 25 03:24:19 EST 2015: START daily cron run
__________________________________________________________________________
/var/lib/openshift/55a000094/app-root/runtime/repo//.openshift/cron/daily/update_dave_list:
WARNING:py.warnings:/var/lib/openshift/55a000094/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_crontab-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/django_crontab/crontab.py:13: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.uti$
  from django.utils.importlib import import_module
Wed Nov 25 03:24:38 EST 2015
/usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/cron/bin/cron_runjobs.sh: line 114: 375681 Killed                  $executor "$SCRIPTS_DIR"
Warning: daily cron run terminated as it exceeded max run time
```

I thought the problem was with `update_dave_list`. But when I print date in `update_dave_list` file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/var/lib/openshift/55a000094/python/virtenv/bin/python /var/lib/openshift/55a000094/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/digrin/manage.py crontab run 18e10bf4fb92741b69745d8a480230a3 # update dave lists
date
```

I realized that date was printed in log -> `update_dave_list` was **successfully completed**! (`Wed Nov 25 03:24:38 EST 2015`) So problem must be in openshift, that won't end `update_dave_list` process or another file is correctly picked up, but it is written to log after it is successfully finished(which never happens). Second idea is more logical. I had one file, that was done within 20 minutes on my localhost, but on openshift it did not complete on time. I fixed this by splitting this long running cron to multiple parts (hourly cron) and now it looks like it runs ok.
Thanks for help! I understand that not many people here use Openshift and without many logs and info it is not easy task to debug! Thanks again for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

No enough reputations to add comment, so I have to add an answer as a comment.

Just in case, are you sure that `urlopen()` could get the xls on OpenShift? Maybe firewall or something else blocks this request. You should add more logs in the code.

Comment: I have run code manually on openshift and it ends in 20 seconds. Also when I uncomment `update_dave_list` it ends with error: max run time. Check EDIT1 please.

Comment: I would add logs, but I can not simulate cron. I need to wait a day for every change I make to find out it does not work. :(

Comment: I gave you bounty since there were no other answers. Hope you can comment now ;)

Comment: @Lucas03 Thanks very much!